# Limit the encrypted result using AES

Tags: c#, aes

I need to encrypt a text (16 chars), preferably using AES, and I need limit the length of the result encrypted text (14 or 16 characteres). The encrypted has to be only chars and numbers (not '=', '?', ...) Is it possible?

I'll need to get back the original text from the cipher text(encrypted).

Is there a way to do this using RijndaelManaged (System.Security.Cryptography
)?

Comment: When you say "The encrypted has to be only chars and numbers" do you mean the original text or the result?

Comment: @jon-skeet The result. I don´t really need to use RijndaelManaged, if necessary, I could use something else, but I would rather AES.

Answer (score 4):

The cypher-text needs to be at least as long(in an entropic sense) as plain-text. You can't losslessly compress arbitrary texts. So if you limit your output to log2(10+2*26)*16=95 bits the input can't have any more entropy than that. This has nothing to do with AES, it's a mathematical limitation that applies to all lossless encodings.

What's a character? A `byte` a `char` or a unicode-codepoint?

AES has the additional problem that it's a block cypher, the minimum output size is equal to the blocksize, 128bits. And since the output appears random it can't be compressed after encrypting. And that already exceeds your limit. And most encryption modes add a bit of additional padding.

There are functions which map arbitrary length input to constant length output. They are called hash-functions. But following the pidgeon-hole-principle they map multiple inputs to an output. So you can't get back the input for all possible inputs.

Comment: A char. Because the cypher-text will be printed in a tag and the user will inform it in another system. This system will use the same routine used to generate the cypher-text to get the original encrypted data.

Comment: As I said your size demands are a mathematical impossibility unless the input string has an extremely low entropy for its length.

Comment: @CodesInChaos So you're saying that the length of the encrypted output cannot be controlled (or limited) ? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: I also have a similar kind of requirement where I want to limit the length of the encrypted string to a max 60 chars. Did you find any existing algorithm fulfiling this.

Comment: @Ankit_ceo2 1) How long is the plaintext? (in bytes, not chars) 2) Is the output limit 60 chars or 60 bytes? And what charset? 3) Do you need encryption, or hashing? i.e. do you need to be able to decrypt?

Comment: 1) My plaintext is 400 bytes long   2) Output limit is 60 chars long    3) I need encryption only and no decryption. But for the same input each time the encrypted value should be the same

Comment: @Ankit_ceo2 Sounds like you need a PRF (e.g. HMAC-SHA-2), not encryption.